# Arduino resets randomly when using a DC motor

Tags: arduino, mosfet, dc-motor, p-channel

Following a question I posted here a few months ago [Using P-Channel mosfet with arduino](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512561/using-p-channel-mosfet-with-arduino) I'm using pchannel MOSFET for activating a CR02 valve like this one https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1938516987.html?spm=a219c.search0302.3.30.33c06d8djwoxkt&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=42bb562b-db52-4060-8454-5a31a442a8ec&algo_expid=42bb562b-db52-4060-8454-5a31a442a8ec-4

[image]

This valve has 3 wires, one goes to +12V the other goes to GND and the remaning one is used to open/close the valve, if this wire is conected to +12V it opens the valve and if it's unconnected it closes the valve. I'm using the following circuit to operate this valve

[image]

```
VIN = +12V
QD = Arduino PIN
QDV = Valve control wire
```

It kind of works, I can open and close the valve but once every 6 or 7 times opening or closing it causes the arduino to reset and I don't know why. I'm using a 2A power supply and the specifications of the valve says it consumes 100mA so it should be enough, I'm also using a diode to protect from the spike of voltage when the motor is turned off, any idea what can be causing the problem?

Comment: Might be a 'ground loop'. Can you show us a photo of the wiring?

Comment: 1n4001 could be a little slow.

Comment: Which kind of diode should be better?

Comment: A fast switching diode, but also it could be that your PSU has no input filter and very low capacitance. A differential choke or LC filter would also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Marko wrote, a slow diode can do quite a bit of trouble. Let's look at his model to see if we can find something.
[image: dióda1]

Yes, it is here:
[image: dióda2]

Since it was a load around 100mA, let's try a small switching diode:
[image: dióda3]

It got significantly better, but this diode will still be small here. Let's look at a better one:
[image: dióda4]

So the diode would be fine. If we’re already modeling, let’s do something about the huge latency caused by the too high value Gate resistor:
[image: dióda5]

The 10k resistor was changed to 1k and a miracle happened:
[image: dióda6]

The delay was almost completely gone. So replacing a diode and a resistor has improved the system a lot. Finally, here are all the interesting signs from this tiny system:
[image: dióda7]

If nothing helps, replace the ground wire with a thicker one. :)

Comment: I like that you have shown the troubleshooting process and not only the final answer, very instructional, hats off

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an unsatisfactory-looking fix, but you may be able to improve the by slowing the turn-on of the MOSFET (turn-off is already slow).

For example, add a 10K resistor series with the MOSFET gate.

That will reduce the demands on layout, bypassing, and even the diode since it will further slow turn-off.